# MediaPlayer start and stop on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a ListView and when I click on a row I play a sound.

If a sound is playing and I click on another row the first one should stop and the second start.

If I don't release the MediaPlayer the application crashes, but this delays the execution of the next sounds.

What I'm doing wrong? This is my code:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        if(!isPlaying){
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,soundid[position]);
            mPlayer.start();
            isPlaying = true; // reproducir es true

        }else{

            isPlaying = false;
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.reset();
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,soundid[position]);
            mPlayer.start();
            isPlaying = true;

        }

        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                mPlayer.release();
                isPlaying = false;
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: why not release it in the else branch, as well?

Comment: I've corrected the code. The problem is to do the release takes a long time and slows next sound reproduction.

Comment: Where is mPlayer declared? at Activity level?

Comment: just at the beginning of the activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this type of implementation you are creating several instances of media player and not releasing them can cause an exception [(refer here)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29). I would suggest you to re-use the already existing media player instance. You can accomplish your goals by doing something like this.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    if(!isPlaying){
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setDataSource(soundid[position]);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true;

    }else{

        isPlaying = false;
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.reset();
        mPlayer.setDataSource(soundid[position]);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true;

    }

    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
            mPlayer.release();
            isPlaying = false;
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why creating the MediaPlayer again?

You can set the file using `'setDataSource'`.
See here: [android developer website: MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29)

[Example here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to take an action when the play is completed; you may consider to use SoundPool: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner implementation,

```
public class PlayMedia{
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
Context context;
boolean isPlaying;

PlayMedia(Context c){
    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
            isPlaying = false;
        }
    });
    this.context = c;
}

public boolean stopResetAndPlay(int ResID){
    if(isPlaying){
         isPlaying = false;
         mMediaPlayer.stop();
         mMediaPlayer.reset();
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(ResID);
            if (afd == null) return false;
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd);
            afd.close();
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        }catch(IOException io){
            Log.i("Playing ", io.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        isPlaying = true;
    }else{
        try {
            this.mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(ResID);
            if (afd == null) return false;
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            isPlaying = true;
        }catch(IOException io){
            Log.i("Playing ", io.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}}
```

and this is how you can use the class inside any activity

```
PlayMedia mPlayer = new PlayMedia(context);
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("identifer_string", "raw", context.getPackageName());
mPlayer.stopResetAndPlay(resID);
```